# Ajax call on MVC works only when the page is set up as startup page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm very new with MVC, so please bear with my obvious questions

I created a simple MVC2 website in VS2010

I added a controlled in the controller folder
Controller code:

```
namespace MVC2TestApp.Controllers
{
    using MVC2TestApp.Models;
    public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /People/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
      //  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPeople(PeopleModel person)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(PeopleModel person)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <button id="btnTest">Test</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('ready got executed');
            $('#btnTest').click(function () {
               // debugger;
                try {
                    var person = { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Soap", Email: "a@b.c" };

                    alert(1);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Add',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: person,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert('step 3');
                            alert(result);
                        },
                        failure: function (result) {
                            alert('step 4');
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.responseText);
                } 

            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

People Controller:

```
namespace MVC2TestApp.Models
{
    public class PeopleModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email{get;set;}
    }
}
```

I set People page as my start up page by setting it up in properties of solution-->Web-->Start Action->Specific Page : People\

This works just as expected, I get the object in controller.

But when the startup page is set as Home, the code doesn't hit the controller. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I tried changing the RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax. But that didn't help.

Global.asax code

```
namespace MVC2TestApp
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },// Parameter defaults
                new string[] { "MVC2TestApp.Controllers" }//This code was added to try to fix the problem
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

It's an MVC2 application. I have VS2010 Professional edition.

Comment: Did You try changing it in the RouteConfig.cs in AppStart folder?

Comment: What if you change the url in the ajax call from "Add" to "People/Add"?

Comment: @scheien That worked. Thanks a ton. It was not working a while ago. I had tried that. But now it works. If I keep your suggestion and Change the start up page back to People doesn't work though. (i think this is what I did wrong) Is it because of relative paths? So when I change it to People, may be Ajax is looking into People\People\Add?

Comment: @Reddy Where is the AppStart Folder. It's not in my solution Folder. Do I need to add it manually?

Comment: It must be created on start of a new MVC project. I have never wrked in MVC2 may be this feature is depricated in mvc2.

Comment: try this ` routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reference the full path to your action in your js.

You can get the full path by using this method (`http://localhost:50000/People/Add`):

```
@Url.Action("Add", "People", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null)
```

Then it will not matter which page you are on, you will always be able to call the same action, and no hassle with relative urls.

Sample:

```
      $('#btnTest').click(function () {
           // debugger;
            try {
                var person = { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Soap", Email: "a@b.c" };
                var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "People", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null)';
                alert("Url: " + url);
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: person,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("Success!");
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    failure: function (result) {
                        alert("Fail!");
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.responseText);
            } 

        });
```